# 5!=6 unless I am missing something?

Tags: support, flags

[image]

Ok, 3 spam flags. I see. And 3 attention flags? I can see only 2.
And my profile shows 6 flags too.

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: Hint: Asking for people to not downvote you over the internet, will result with people downvoting you over the internet.

Comment: But my question is stupid and I can even delete it!

Comment: Questions with upvoted answers cannot be deleted by their owner. Don't get upset over downvotes, they really don't matter.

Comment: @SecondRikudo I know. Thanks for the second argument.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cast two flags on the question that's on the top of the list: a spam flag and a off-topic flag.